# dataexplorer error after SSL is set on CKAN

Tags: ckan

I set up the SSL in ckan using tutorial: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/SSL

Everything looks fine, except the datastore information that is showing the following error: "Could not load view: DataProxy returned an error (Data transformation failed. error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to connect to server at URL:"

Does anyone has any idea whats going on? I tried to access the datastore url and it looks fine: "{
  "help": "\n        Get help at:\n        http://ckan-service-provider.readthedocs.org/."
}"

When I enter into the datastore page to upload the document I get the error

"Erro: File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs) File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 300, in push_to_datastore resource = get_resource(resource_id, ckan_url, api_key) File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/src/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 250, in get_resource 'Authorization': api_key} File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 110, in post return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs) File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/ckan/datapusher/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send raise SSLError(e, request=request) SSLError(SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed'),),)"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's an error in the datapusher.

http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/using.html#configuring-ssl-verification

I could not disable the SSL verification. Somehow the file (datapusher_settings.py) does not reflect the changes I wanted.